# Database column doesn't get updated when button being pressed

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have 2 functions in my php file. 1 to generate a random image out of my database. 1 to vote on the picture (cool or not cool). It's a little project so there are not alot of rows in my database. Just around 10-15 max.

My function for the random image :

```
public function randomImage(){
$con = new Database();
$con->connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM fotos order by RAND() LIMIT 1';
$sth = $con->myconn->query($sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result['foto'] ).'"/>';
}
```

My function for the voting (cool or not cool) :

```
public function voteImage($fotoid){
$con = new Database();
$con->connect();
$sql = 'UPDATE fotos SET cool = cool + 1 WHERE fotoid=?';
$stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $fotoid);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();  
}
```

My code in the other php file:

```
<?php 
$image = new Image();
$image->randomImage();
?>
<form action="opdracht2.php" method="post" name="cool">
<input type="submit" value="Cool" name="cool" />
<input type="submit" value="Niet Cool" name="ncool" />
<input type="hidden" name="fotoid" value="<?php echo $result['fotoid']; ?>" />
</form>


<?php 


if(isset($_POST['cool']))
{
 $voteimage = new Image();
 $voteimage->voteImage($_POST['fotoid']);
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There are no error messages. When the button cool is being pressed the page refreshes but nothing happens. It just loads the page but in the database the cool column doesn't get updated by 1. When I test out the queries in my database it updates. So I think I'm doing something wrong in the PHP code.

Comment: Where is `$result['fotoid'];` set?

Comment: what do you mean @Mihai

Comment: I think that `value="<?php echo $result['fotoid'];` will be null in your HTML.Try it hardcoded for debugging purposes

Comment: @Mihai Isn't this ` $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth); ` for that ?

Comment: It is out of scope outside the function

Comment: When I made it echo $result['fotoid'] it gives the error:  Undefined variable: result. So you're right but how can make it defined?

Comment: Create another function which will return a single id,echo that out for value or modify the first function to return a single id insted of <img blah blah

Comment: what's with the duped `name="cool"`?

Comment: ah I changed that now to fotos @Fred-ii-.
When I create another function I can't seem to return the id? Can you give me an example mihai?

Comment: when using ? to bind parameters, i always though you needed to use integers to refference them. so wouldn't "i" be 1?

Comment: Thank you for your help aswell, Answer is down below. This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find updated code

```
public function randomImage(){
$con = new Database();
$con->connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM fotos order by RAND() LIMIT 1';
$sth = $con->myconn->query($sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
return $result;
}
```

your code in the other php file:

```
<?php 
$image = new Image();
$result= $image->randomImage();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result['foto'] ).'"/>';

?>
<form action="opdracht2.php" method="post" name="cool">
<input type="submit" value="Cool" name="cool" />
<input type="submit" value="Niet Cool" name="ncool" />
<input type="hidden" name="fotoid" value="<?php echo $result['fotoid']; ?>" />
</form>


<?php 


if(isset($_POST['cool']))
{
 $voteimage = new Image();
 $voteimage->voteImage($_POST['fotoid']);
}
```

Your function for the voting (cool or not cool) :

```
public function voteImage($fotoid){
$con = new Database();
$con->connect();
$sql = 'UPDATE fotos SET cool = cool + 1 WHERE fotoid=?';
$stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $fotoid);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();  
}
```

Other then this I think everything is Ok.